# Correct way of using HashMap for logging in log4j2

Tags: hashmap, log4j2

I want to generate key value pairs in log4j2 but i dont want to define a new name for the Hashmap that i create everytime. Will the below code work on all scenarios or is there a chance that GC will cleanup the earlier Hashmap objects eventhough i passed the reference to log4j class before it logs the map asynchronously?

```
    Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    myMap.put("card_token", "abcdefg");
    myMap.put("action", "start of sample app");
    myMap.put("desc", "start of sample splunk app");
    logger.error(new MapMessage(myMap));
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        myMap.put("action", "inside the loop"); 
        myMap.put("desc", "inside the loop of the sample app");
        myMap.put("loop_count", String.valueOf(i));
        logger.error(new MapMessage(myMap));
    }
    myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
    myMap.put("action", "end of sample app");
    myMap.put("desc", "end of sample splunk app");
    logger.error(new MapMessage(myMap));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't worry, GC won't clean up anything that still has references to it. The HashMap won't  be GC'ed until after it was logged.